# Where can I find Google Assistant "Share screenshot" button?

Tags: android-12, google-assistant

Despite:

[image: ![enter image description here]
https://techhelpkb.medium.com/bypass-an-android-apps-screenshot-restriction-34ee4b79b284

and

[image: 2]

https://support.google.com/assistant/answer/7393909?hl=en-GB&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid

when I hold the Home button on this Samsung phone, I get a part-screen window saying "Try saying" but missing "What’s on my screen?" button.

If I tap the mic icon and say "Hey Google", I get a bigger window with a horizontal list of buttons including "What’s on my screen?", but tapping that gets only a box saying "Play, hum or sing a song."

So, how do I find a "What’s on my screen?" (or anything else) that actually offers "Share screenshot"?

Thanks.

PS Assistant > Settings > General

[image]

PPS Use screen context gives

[image]

Comment: Have you turned it on? Open assistant and say open assistant settings > general > use screen context

Comment: Have I turned it on? No. Is it turned on? I do not know. Use screen context does not offer it.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you attach a screenshot of what you can see in `assistant settings > general`

Comment: Attaching is not offered so I have embedded one.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what you see if you press the "Use screen context" section on this screen?

Comment: Also, there appears to be a pretty prevalent bug with this feature, it doesn't appear to work at all on my Pixel 6 Pro either, just turns on the "hum a song" command (https://www.reddit.com/r/GooglePixel/comments/sgcqct/anyone_else_having_issues_with_screen_context_for/), (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145374256?pli=1), (https://www.google.com/search?q=what%27s+on+my+screen+google+assistant+not+working&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS1038US1038&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#ip=1)

Comment: @ChrisJJ Analyse on screen text is the same thing and you've already enabled it. Instead of searching for the button try saying "what's on my screen" to the google assistant. It should work

Comment: That gives "Play sing or hum a song".